# Tabulator (4.1) replacing new Column value/ formatter

Tags: javascript, image-uploading, tabulator

I've added a new column in **Tabulator** with this column definition

```
table.addColumn({title:"idCopy", field: "idCopy" ,sortable:false, formatter:uploadID,width:100, align:"center",cellClick:function(e, cell){
  function selected(){
    var fileName = formInput.value;
    cell.getRow().getData().idCopy = fileName;

  }
var f = document.createElement("form");
var formInput = document.createElement('input');
formInput.onclick = "selected(cell,f,formInput)" ;
var s = document.createElement("input");
s.setAttribute('type',"submit");
f.appendChild(formInput);
f.appendChild(s);
f.onClick = formInput.click();
}}, false);
```

I've added more lines to define each form with ID similar to this `f.id = "f_" +  cell.getRow().getData().id ;` so each form is unique and `uploadID` function look like this

```
  var uploadID = function(cell, formatterParams, onRendered){ 

return "<i class='fa fa-print'>upload ID</i>";
```

which is what i got from the official resources http://tabulator.info/docs/4.1/format#icon
the problem is whenever i pick the file `cell.getRow().getData().idCopy` has the value of `fileName` which is exactly what i wanted but on the table's cell it still says `upload ID` instead of the value of `fileName`'s value

so the user will have no idea that he have just picked the file and the system is ready to upload it.

is there is a way to **replace** `upload ID` with the `fileName`  value or **refresh** those cells ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed it by applying row reformat

first I've added a condition in `var uploadID = function(cell, formatterParams, onRendered){}`

for example :

```
var uploadID = function(cell, formatterParams, onRendered){ //plain text value
var x = cell.getValue();
if ( x == null ){ // do something}
else{ // do something }
return /*something*/;
```

then in `cellClick:function(e, cell){}`

I've added the following at the end of my code

```
    var row = cell.getRow();
    row.reformat();
```

Comment: calling the reformat function will result in unnecessary rendering of the entire row, if you call the update function on the row component passing in the updated properties it will redraw only the fields that are changed

Answer (score 4):

If you are changing any data in the row then you need to call the ***update*** function on the row component for that row, passing in the updated data parameters:

```
row.update({id:"f_" +  cell.getRow().getData().id});
```

this will then update the values correctly